# How to add XML file with event reciver

Tags: event-handlers, xml, file

I am creating a event reciver for the list, for that i need to get some data from XML file. currently i have placed the xml file in my local system. Actually where do i need to add the xml file. Is that Mapped folder?. I have tried to add file to the mapped folder but its not loading in my event reciver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add this file to the mapping folder Layouts for example, even add this file to embeded resources of receiver's assembly, if you don't need to share this xml with other modules.
When you will add file to the mapping folder Layout, to get it, use path a kind of `http://hostname/_layouts/your_file_name.xml`
this path will be accessible on any web, becouse SharePoint maps this folder to each of them, for example `http://hostname/subweb/_layouts/your_file_name.xml`